# How to insert Image of product programmaticaly through url

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, curl

How to insert image in magento product via url. Products are inserting but without images 
$urlToImage = 'image'; has the url of image. and How do i insert products option?

```
            <?php

            include_once("vendor.php");
            include_once("category.php");
            include_once("latest.php");


            $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
            require_once $mageFilename;
            Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            Mage::app();
            umask(0);

            $offerJsonURL    =  'http://affilnow.com/component/controller.php';
            $Products        =  'get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id';
            $Categories      =  'get_parent_categories';
            $Latest          =  'get_latest_products';

            $fk_= new vendor_data($affiliateID, $token);
            $fk_Categories= new category($affiliateID, $token);
            $fk_Latest = new latest($affiliateID,$token);


            $stores= vendor_data::getVendor($offerJsonURL, 'json');
            $categories= category::getCat($offerJsonURL, 'json');
            $latest = latest::getLatest($offerJsonURL, 'json');



            $product_id='product_id';
            $name='name';
            $description='description';
            $short_d='short_description';
            $quantity='quantity';
            $weight = 'weight';
            $rate ='price';
            $sku='sku';
            $tax='None';
            $visibility= 4;
            $status='status';
            $meta_title='meta_title';
            $meta_description='meta_description';
            $meta_keyword='meta_keyword';
            $tag='tag';
            $model='model';
            $upc='upc';
            $ean='ean';
            $jan='jan';
            $isbn='isbn';
            $mpn='mpn';
            $location='location';
            $image='image';
            $stock='stock_status';
            $category ='categories';
            $options = 'options' ;
            $urlToImage = 'image';





               $i=1;
                foreach ($stores['data'][$Products] as $review) {
            $i++;
                 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
                 $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
                  try {
                     $product
                    ->setStoreId(0)
                    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                    ->setAttributeSetId(4)
                    ->setTypeId('simple')
                    ->setSku($review[$sku])
                    ->setName($review[$name])
                    ->setWeight($review[$weight])
                    ->setTaxClassId('0')
                    ->setPrice($review[$rate])
                    ->setMetaTitle($review[$meta_title])
                    ->setMetaKeyword($review[$meta_keyword])
                    ->setMetaDescription($review[$meta_description])
                    ->setDescription($review[$description])
                    ->setShortDescription($review[$description])
                    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->setStockData(array(
                            'qty' => $review[$quantity],
                            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // use global config ?
                            'manage_stock'            => 0, // shoudl we manage stock or not?
                            'is_in_stock'             => 1,

                        )
                    )



                    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery($review[$urlToImage], array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false)
                    ->setCategoryIds(array($review[$category]));

                   $product->save();
                   $err = curl_error($curl);
                  curl_close($curl);
                 }catch (Exception $e) {
                   Mage::log($e->getMessage());
               }

             }
             echo $i."Products upload";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is because your images are coming as URL links (`$review[$urlToImage]`), and that's why you cannot import them directly.

Instead, I've added part of code which downloads your image into `media/import` directory, and then executes import process.

```
<?php
    include_once("vendor.php");
    include_once("category.php");
    include_once("latest.php");

    $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    Mage::app();
    umask(0);

    $offerJsonURL    =  'http://affilnow.com/component/controller.php';
    $Products        =  'get_product_list_by_category_id_and_or_vendor_id';
    $Categories      =  'get_parent_categories';
    $Latest          =  'get_latest_products';

    $fk_= new vendor_data($affiliateID, $token);
    $fk_Categories= new category($affiliateID, $token);
    $fk_Latest = new latest($affiliateID,$token);

    $stores= vendor_data::getVendor($offerJsonURL, 'json');
    $categories= category::getCat($offerJsonURL, 'json');
    $latest = latest::getLatest($offerJsonURL, 'json');

    $product_id='product_id';
    $name='name';
    $description='description';
    $short_d='short_description';
    $quantity='quantity';
    $weight = 'weight';
    $rate ='price';
    $sku='sku';
    $tax='None';
    $visibility= 4;
    $status='status';
    $meta_title='meta_title';
    $meta_description='meta_description';
    $meta_keyword='meta_keyword';
    $tag='tag';
    $model='model';
    $upc='upc';
    $ean='ean';
    $jan='jan';
    $isbn='isbn';
    $mpn='mpn';
    $location='location';
    $image='image';
    $stock='stock_status';
    $category ='categories';
    $options = 'options' ;
    $urlToImage = 'image';

    $i=1;
    foreach ($stores['data'][$Products] as $review) {
        $i++;

        $image_url  = $review[$urlToImage];
        $image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1);
        $filename   = md5($image_url . $review[$sku]).'.'.$image_type;
        $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename;
        file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url)));

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");
        try {
            $product
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
            ->setAttributeSetId(4)
            ->setTypeId('simple')
            ->setSku($review[$sku])
            ->setName($review[$name])
            ->setWeight($review[$weight])
            ->setTaxClassId('0')
            ->setPrice($review[$rate])
            ->setMetaTitle($review[$meta_title])
            ->setMetaKeyword($review[$meta_keyword])
            ->setMetaDescription($review[$meta_description])
            ->setDescription($review[$description])
            ->setShortDescription($review[$description])
            ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->setStockData(array(
                    'qty' => $review[$quantity],
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, // use global config ?
                    'manage_stock'            => 0, // shoudl we manage stock or not?
                    'is_in_stock'             => 1,

                )
            )
            ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
            ->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false)
            ->setCategoryIds(array($review[$category]));

           $product->save();
           $err = curl_error($curl);
           curl_close($curl);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
    echo $i."Products upload";
```

Comment: Great Thats working